# Frameticks disappear when exporting plot to eps in 11.3

Tags: plotting, export, eps-format

I experienced frameticks disappearing when exporting plot to eps in 11.3 version. 11.0 works fine. Exporting to pdf in 11.3 works fine. The plot in the notebook has ticks.

MME:

```
Plot[Sin[r], {r, 0.01, 5}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"r", "Sin[r]"}]
Export[FileNameJoin[{"~/", "test.eps"}], %];
```